# Windows Phone share via different email accounts

Tags: c#, email, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, share

I want to implement the share feature in my application just like page sharing in IE. When it came to email sharing, I wanted to display the list of email accounts before I launch the EmailComposeTask(), but I have 2 problems:

- I can't figure out how to retrieve the list of accounts that the user defined in 'email+accounts' settings: Gmail, Hotmail, outlook, ...
- In the EmailComposeTask, I can't specify from which account I'm sending from programmatically

Any ideas ?

[image: share page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't retrieve the list of email accounts that the user defined with the current Windows Phone SDK (privacy reasons I guess).

The only way to send an email is via the `EmailComposeTask`. If the user has multiple accounts registered, he will be prompted which one to use.

Comment: but how could the IE retrieve them ?

Comment: I guess IE has a privileged access to this kind of information.